# Do I need a wallet to deploy a smart contract into Ethereum network?

Tags: contract-deployment, wallets

I am new to Ethereum world and I would like to know if developers who desire to deploy their smart contract in the Ethereum mainnet or testnet, **need to create previously a digital wallet with real or test Ether respectively.** ???

**In other words, is the following process from a developer's perspective correct?**

1. Create digital wallet (is create **account** more correct ???)
2. Fund wallet with real or test ether (is fund **account** more correct ???)
3. Write Smart contract
4. Compile code
5. Deploy smart contract

Comment: For testing purposes use remix.ethereum.org an IDE for solidity development. For deploying to a testnet a address is required.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert but all you need is a compatible wallet that can hold ERC20 Token, there are many wallets out there compatible to ERC-20 tokens, most popular ones Trust, Metamask..

you deploy the smart contract and connect wallet, and that's it, your tokens are send to your wallet...

there is no need to create a hard wallet such specifically for Android, Ios, you can, but I think you just want to create a token and have the tokens in a wallet right?